# XQuery Update Data

Tags: xml, xquery, xmlspy

I am trying to update some XML data using XMLspy.

Here is the data I have...

```
<Orders>
    <Order_x0020_ID>30</Order_x0020_ID>
    <Employee_x0020_ID>9</Employee_x0020_ID>
    <Customer_x0020_ID>27</Customer_x0020_ID>
    <Order_x0020_Date>2006-01-15T00:00:00</Order_x0020_Date>
    <Shipped_x0020_Date>2006-01-22T00:00:00</Shipped_x0020_Date>
    <Shipper_x0020_ID>2</Shipper_x0020_ID>
    <Ship_x0020_Name>Karen Toh</Ship_x0020_Name>
    <Ship_x0020_Address>789 27th Street</Ship_x0020_Address>
    <Ship_x0020_City>Las Vegas</Ship_x0020_City>
    <Ship_x0020_State_x002F_Province>NV</Ship_x0020_State_x002F_Province>
    <Ship_x0020_ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code>99999</Ship_x0020_ZIP_x002F_Postal_x0020_Code> 
    <Ship_x0020_Country_x002F_Region>USA</Ship_x0020_Country_x002F_Region>
    <Shipping_x0020_Fee>200</Shipping_x0020_Fee>
    <Taxes>0</Taxes>
    <Payment_x0020_Type>Check</Payment_x0020_Type>
    <Paid_x0020_Date>2006-01-15T00:00:00</Paid_x0020_Date>
    <Tax_x0020_Rate>0</Tax_x0020_Rate>
    <Status_x0020_ID>3</Status_x0020_ID>
</Orders>
```

I'm using this XQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0";
insert nodes 
  <Orders>
    <Order_x0020_ID>999</Order_x0020_ID>
  </Orders>
into doc("Orders.xml")
```

This should create another order in the Orders.xml file. However, when trying to run it, it does not. This is the error I get:

```
Unexpected token 'nodes'

XPST0003: The expression around '"1.0"; insert nodes <Orders>' is not a  valid instance of the XQuery grammar
```

I wish the output data to be:

```
<Orders>
    <Order_x0020_ID>999</Order_x0020>
</Orders>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: your query seems grammatically correct. The only thing that is wrong with it is that its currently producing two document elements. You should use into doc("Orders.xml")/Orders instead. But from the error you're getting it seems the processor that you're using doesn't (fully?) support xquery update. I'm not an expert on the capabilities of xmlspy though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `xquery version "1.0";` declaration since XQuery update is a separate extension. If you're going through the XMLSPY GUI, you just need to set the processor and version you're using:

[image]